# Rails 4: collection_check_box error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-forms, actionview

I am building a form that launches a new Campaign. With this Campaign, you can choose a Zip file and/or some PDF files. Zip and PDF files are all stored in an Uploads table.

So far, it appears I can choose a Zip file, however, once I add the `collection_check_box` for PDFs, create a Campaign, I receive the following error...

```
expected Array (got String) for param `upload_ids'
```

My form looks like this..

```
<%= form_for @campaign, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :name, class: "right-label" %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.label :comment, "Comments" %>
   <%= f.text_area :comment %>


   <%= f.label :zip_file, class: "right-label" %>

   <%= f.collection_select :upload_ids, Upload.where(file_type: ".zip"), :id, :file_name, include_blank: "Include a Zip File" do |b| %>
        <%= b.option + File.basename(b.text, '.*') %>
    <% end %>

   <%= f.label :pdf_files %>

<ul><%= f.collection_check_boxes :upload_ids, Upload.where(file_type: ".pdf"), :id, :file_name do |b| %>
    <li><%= b.label do %>
        <%= b.check_box + File.basename(b.text,'.*') %>
    </li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Here is a the error displayed on the server as requested.

```
[2015-06-01 14:50:57] ERROR Rack::Utils::ParameterTypeError: expected Array (got String) for param `upload_ids'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:142:in `normalize_params'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:156:in `normalize_params'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:117:in `block in parse_nested_query'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:114:in `each'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:114:in `parse_nested_query'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/request.rb:369:in `parse_query'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/request.rb:215:in `POST'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:39:in `method_override_param'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:27:in `method_override'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:in `call'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    /Users/Josh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

**EDIT**

If I delete one of the collection blocks (zip or pdf), my Campaign creation is successful.

It appears as if there is a conflict with my "upload_ids" on both the Zip file and PDF file selection methods above. Even though my model relationship states that a Campaign `has_many: uploads, through: uploadable` and `has_many: uploadable`, it's trying to accept both - the Zip and PDF/s - one instance of `upload_id`.

I'm still unsure how to get around this. Any help is appreciated.

**controllers/campaigns_controller.rb**

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @campaigns = Campaign.all.order("created_at DESC")
      end

      def new
        @campaign = Campaign.new
      end

      def create
        @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)

        if @campaign.save
            flash[:success] = "Campaign Successfully Launched!"
            redirect_to @campaign
        else
            flash[:error] = "There was a problem launching your Campaign."
            redirect_to new_campaign_path
        end
      end

      def show
        @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
      end

  private

      def campaign_params
        params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :comment)
      end
end
```

**log/development.log**

```
Started GET "/campaigns/new" for ::1 at 2015-06-01 18:54:19 -0700
Processing by CampaignsController#new as HTML
  [1m[35mUpload Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "uploads".* FROM "uploads"
  [1m[36mUpload Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "uploads".* FROM "uploads" WHERE "uploads"."file_type" = $1[0m  [["file_type", ".zip"]]
  [1m[35mUpload Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "uploads".* FROM "uploads" WHERE "uploads"."file_type" = $1  [["file_type", ".pdf"]]
  Rendered campaigns/_form.html.erb (6.6ms)
  Rendered campaigns/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 80.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

**Update #1**

Another Developer friend noted that I cannot use "upload_ids" for both `collection_selects`. That is also apparent in my experiments above. So how do I allow a user to associate the object with 2 other objects from a separate model/table?

I changed one `collection_select` object param to be `uploadable_ids` but that is a random name I placed. I have no clue what to put as that parameter. Now I receive the flash[:error] `"There was a problem launching your Campaign."`

**Update #2**

I've tried many suggestions including the ones on this posting but still struggling to get this to work. The `select_tag` throws and `undefined method` so for the time being, I'm simply using `select`. I tried adding the `upload_ids[]` yet was thrown an error that there needed to be more arguments.

I'm also confused on whether I need to add anything to my controller. Will my Active Record associations be enough when I decide to query which Campaign is associated with which files?

Here is the zip and pdf portion of the form in its current state..

```
<%= f.label :data_file, class: "right-label" %>

<%= f.select :upload_ids, 
    options_from_collection_for_select(
    Upload.where(file_type: ".zip"), :id, :file_name), 
    {include_blank: "Include a Zip File"}, {mulitple: true} %>

<%= f.label :additional_files %>

<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:upload_ids, 
    Upload.where(file_type: ".pdf"), :id, :file_name, 
    { mulitple: true }) do |b| %>
            <%= b.label do %>
              <%= b.check_box + File.basename(b.text,'.*') %>
            <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If it is of any added help, here the model relationships:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  has_many :uploadable
  has_many :uploads, through: :uploadable
end

class Uploadable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :upload
end

class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :uploadable
  has_many :campaigns, through: :uploadable
end
```

Comment: show the full error stack.. Better developement logs from console

Comment: @R_O_R - Added the console output above.

Comment: @R_O_R - Updated post with a recent discovery.

Comment: Please post the logs.

Comment: And also post the controller code.

Comment: Try adding `:upload_ids => []` to `campaign_params` `params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :comment,:upload_ids => [])`

Comment: @Pavan - Hey Pavan, that unfortunately didn't work, but I did add an update on some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue I see is that your checkboxes are submitting an array parameter (you can select multiple check boxes) but your `collection_select` is trying to submit a singular value. The mixing of the two is what causes the Rack::Utils::ParameterTypeError

Your `uploads` association is a has_many so using an array parameter is the right thing to do. The simplest possible thing you can do is make the select a multiple choice one, by adding the `multiple: true` option. Note that this must go in a separate hash to your `include_blank` option.

To keep a separate select I think you'll need to drop down to calling select_tag and specify `upload_ids[]` as the input name. You can still use `options_from_collection_for_select` to generate the option tags.

Comment: This is definitely leading me in the right direction. Thank you. Unfortunately I'm still running into errors. When I specify `upload_ids[]` as the input, I am told there is a wrong number of arguments 0 for 1..3. When using select_tag, I get an `undefined method 'select_tag` error. I feel as if the problem is also how I'm using `upload_ids` on both blocks but I'm unsure what else to put. Both blocks do inherit from the same `Upload` table.

Comment: Multiple uses of upload_ids is not on its own a problem. Hard to say more without seeing what you've tried changing

Comment: I appended the post with current code along with the model associations.

Comment: Ah, you may have been trying to call select_tag on the form builder (f) which isn't right - it's just `select_tag "campaign[upload_ids]", ...`

Comment: Ok great. I believe I got the _zip_ portion to work but I had to remove the section that takes off file extension for viewing. In the _pdf_ section, I am now receiving the `undefined method 'campaign[upload_ids]'` error. I've removed the appended loop to take off file extension as well to keep it simple.

Comment: The pdf section should work as is ( `f.collection_check_boxes :upload_ids, ...`)